# Cannot Boot into Raspbian with BerryBoot and Twister on SSD Drive

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues, raspbian-buster, berryboot

I have a raspberry Pi4 8GB and have installed it in an Argon One M.2 Case with a Kingston 128GB SSD Drive.
When viewing a tutorial on how to set it up I opted to install BerryBoot in order to have the option to multiboot into a couple of OS's.
I added Twister OS and Raspbian Desktop Lite
Booting into Twister is fine, however booting into Raspbian it stalls at:

```
A Start job is running for /dev/disk/by-label/boot (37s / 1min 30s)
```

Then this eventually times out waiting for device.

```
"You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl 1 reboot", to reboot, "systemctl defualt" or exit" to boot into default mode.

Cannot open access to console, the root system is locked. See sulogin(8) man page for more details.

Press Enter to continue"
```

The then says its reloading system manager configuration

```
Starting default target
```

And then just loops back to You are in emergency mode.

Any ideas how to resolve?

Is there a BerryBoot Forum?

Answer (score 1):

With the given information, it seems that the bootloader cannot find the root partition. I don't know how BerryBoot works but the error message is also given by the Raspberry Pi OS, if it doesn't find the root partion as specified in `/boot/cmdline.txt`. So you should check this file. It seems it has only set a placeholder `root=/dev/disk/by-label/boot` there and not the real root partition. I'm a little unsure why it is pointing to a `boot` label. Anyway, you can try to replace it with the correct root partition device name. To be on the safe side  I would use the **PARTUUID** of the disk to address it. You can find it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo blkid
```

Locate the right partition and use its PARTUUID for the entry in `/boot/cmdline.txt`, for example:

```
root=PARTUUID=738a4d67-02
```

It's a problem that you can't run the RasPi to execute `blkid`. But the PARTUUID is a property of the SSD drive. You are able to get it if you can mount the drive on another (linux) computer or boot the RasPi with a spare SD Card with a [Raspberry Pi OS Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/).

Comment: So what should the the path to the root partition look like? root=dev/disk/<name_of_ssd_drive>

Comment: @Bill I have updated the answer.

Comment: Ok thanks, but not sure how I will be able to run that command when I cannot get it to boot to a terminal?

Comment: @Bill Of course, that is a problem I did not think of. I have updated the answer again.

Comment: I have installed this OS using Beery Boot, the other OS that is available is Twister OS, this boots up fine. Maybe I could boot Twister and carry out the commands from there?

Comment: @Bill As long as Twister can execute `blkid` and edit `/boot/cmdline.txt` and `/etc/fstab` then it should be possible.

Comment: Ok so finally managed to get around to looking at this. I have just booted the offending Raspberry Pi and it has booted into Twister OS, which is set as default. I have then ssh'd into it on the Mac and ran sudo blkid. Here is the response: `/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="SANDISKSD" LABEL="SANDISKSD" UUID="FF4F-13F5" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="berryboot" UUID="01383b4c-1cd9-43dd-ad0c-710301abcd31" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="af4598dd-02"`

Comment: However if I open a terminal in Twister OS on the offending Pi and run sudo blkid I get two extra lines after `PARTUUID="af4598dd-02"` that are `/dev/mmcblk0: PTTYPE="DOS" /dev/sda1: PARTUID="af4598dd-01

Comment: In Finder on TwisterOS, if I open File System/ cmdline.txt `root=PARTUUID=ea7d046-02

Comment: @Bill The comments are hard to read with unformatted information. Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/120749/edit) your question and add it there.